# Loading pictures from Filechooser

Tags: java, image

My code:

```
 try {
             FileChooser fileChooser = new FileChooser();
             fileChooser.setTitle("Open Resource File");
             fileChooser.getExtensionFilters().add(new FileChooser.ExtensionFilter("PNG", "*.png"));
             File file = fileChooser.showOpenDialog(null);
             BufferedImage originalImage = ImageIO.read(new File(memberView.selectedPicturePath.getText()));
             ImageIO.write(originalImage, ".png", file.getAbsoluteFile());
         } catch (IOException e) {
             System.out.println(e.getMessage());
         }
```

i want to save an image from a random directory to the one specified here but every time i get a Can't read input file! message.

The image i am trying to load actually exists since i am choosing it with the file loader.

Where is the problem in this code?

Answer (score 0):

Check that what method `memberView.selectedPicturePath.getText())` is return, perhaps it is not valid path to your image.

Comment: it returns /res/memberdata/memberId.png

the path exists but the picture does not always exist, depending if the user already has a set profilepicture or not

Comment: If your image not exist in all time your need to check this condition in somewhere else and after ensure if your image is present try to load it.